# Question about "вот вы где"?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

"вот вы где" is a an expression that does not exist in my slovar and when I split it up it does not make sense. I have also run it through the machine.

To give you some context. The guests arrive but the man that was to meet them thought they were in a different car and then doubles back finds them and opens with greeting them with a "hi" and: "вот вы где". Would this expression correspond to: "here you are" or perhaps "welcome" in a way?

Comment: "Ah, here you are", mystery resolved, next case )))

Comment: I'm curious as to why you drop in the non-English word "slovar" here. Do you just mean a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I mean dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This simply means "*There* you are!"

Actually **вот** can be used quite productively with interrogative words to form such expressions of eureka:

> Так **вот почему** он не унаследовал семейный бизнес.

So *that's* why he didn't inherit the family business.

> Значит, **вот куда** вы убежали?

*This* is where you ran to.

> Хорошо, **вот как** мы поступим.

Alright, *this* is how it's going to go.

> **Вот когда** неплохо иметь собаку.

*That's* when it would be nice to have a dog.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Equal to Здесь вы есть, which is not used at all. So, Here you are is an answer.